# Xamarin.Forms.Maps how to get the center of the screen to use it as Lat and Lon coordinates and the zoom level?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I load pins depending on the user's location, but when they move the map I'd like to load new pins by passing the `lat` and `lon` of the center of the screen and then load pins depending on distance from the center of the screen but I just don't know how to get these coordinates as well as the zoom level of the map, for example if the user unzooms to load more pins, how to I get the zoom data ?

Comment: Use the VisibleRegion property

Comment: Thank you Jason, can you write it as an answer so that I can mark it as such ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [VisibleRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.maps.map.visibleregion?view=net-maui-7.0) property of the `Map` control